# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined while trying to edit

Tags: javascript, discord.js, undefined, typeerror

I try to get the guild using the following code:

```js
const guild = Discord.Client.guilds.get("GUILD_ID");
```

But I receive the following error message and I don't understand why:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

`Discord.Client` is a class. What you're looking for is `client.guilds.get("GUILD_ID")` where `client` is a `new Discord.Client()` logged in and ready to use.

The following should work:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log('Bot is connected...');
  let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID'); 
  // OR!
  guild = await client.guilds.fetch('GUILD_ID'); 
  console.log(guild.name)
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```